# jquery dialog custom Close button works only first load, not on second onward loads why?

Tags: jquery

1. In my MVC 3 application I have a link button, upon click on this, a partial view load in jquery dialog.

**View**

```
   <a class="dialogLink" href="/Home/OpenDialog">OPen Dialog</a>
```

**Partial View**

```
<div id="dlgReport"><input type="button" id="closeDialog" value="Close"/></div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult OpenDialog(ViewModel model){
 //setting value
return PartialView(model);}
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, async: false });
  $('.dialogLink').live('click', function () {
     var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
     var dialogDiv = "<div id='" + dialogId + "'></div>";
     var data = $('form').serialize();
     $.post(this.href, data)
     .success(function (result) {
        $(dialogDiv).html(result).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,modal: true,title: 'Test',
        open: function () {
          $('#closeDialog').bind('click', function (e) {
          //debugger;
          $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog().dialog("close");
     });}});})
     return false;});});
```

1. All works good, when I click link button (Open Dialog), a post request will go to controller, fill the data and pass the data to partial view and partial view loaded custom "Close Dialog" button.
2. On first click on "Close Dialog" button, close the dialog but when again I load the dialog, the "Close Dialog" will not work.
3. I check with debugger, second time the ,

   **('#closeDialog').bind('click', function (e) {**

   not called, don't know whats wrong here. Please suggest! Thanks!

Note - IF I used the code "**$(this).dialog('close');**" instead of "**$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog().dialog("close");**", then I am getting unknown error from first time onward on click of "close dialog" button.

Answer (score 0):

you may not bind the event several times.
Try

```
 $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, async: false });
            $('.dialogLink').live('click', function () {
                var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
                var dialogDiv = "<div id='" + dialogId + "'></div>";
                var data = $('form').serialize();
                $.post(this.href, data)
                .success(function (result) {
                    $(dialogDiv).html(result).dialog({
                        autoOpen: true, modal: true, title: 'Test',
                        open: function () {
                            $('#closeDialog').unbind('click', fnBindClick);
                            $('#closeDialog').bind('click',fnBindClick);
                        }
                    });
                })

                function fnBindClick(e) {
                    //debugger;
                    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog().dialog("close");
                } 
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got answer from other stack overflow thread, we need to empty and remove the dialog,

```
$(function () {
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, async: false });
 $('.dialogLink').live('click', function () {
 var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
 var dialogDiv = "<div id='" + dialogId + "'></div>";
 var data = $('form').serialize();
 $.post(this.href, data)
 .success(function (result) {
    $(dialogDiv).html(result).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,modal: true,title: 'Test',
    open: function () {
      $('#closeDialog').bind('click', function (e) {
      //debugger;
      $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog().dialog("close");
      $(this).empty();
      $(this).remove();
 });}});})
 return false;});});
```